# Updating a Certified-but-not-yet-Published Alexa skill

Tags: release, publish, publishing, alexa-skills-kit

My first Alexa skill is almost ready to go public, but I seem to have gotten myself a bit tangled... I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

I asked Amazon to `Certify But Not Publish` this skill, to check that I wasn't missing anything obvious. They did so. Great, but...

Since then, I've uploaded some slightly modified models. Since I'm ready to go, I went to `Validation` and punched `Certify` again. It told me "You cannot submit this skill for review because it has a ‘Certified’ version. Publish or withdraw the previously ‘Certified’ version to submit this skill for review."

`Submission` shows a warning that the most recent validation failed (for the above reason).

OK, I understand. But I'm not sure how to do either of those.

When I look at `Version History`, I do see the previously `Certified` skill version. However, I can't see how to either `publish` or `withdraw` it!

A quick websearch hasn't found anything which clarifies this for me. I *MUST* be missing something obvious -- these operations are on a different page, or something like that. Could someone point me to where I can perform them?

(Yes, I looked at https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/devconsole/test-and-submit-your-skill.html. That doesn't seem to address my situation of having a certified version, having a new version which couldn't yet be certified, and not being sure how to go either forward or backward.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the list of the skill, make sure you select the `dev` or `in review` version and go inside it
2. Go into the certification tab and in the submission menu
3. Click on withdraw from review

[image]

If you don't see that, contact the support

Comment: That's it, I think. It never occurred to me that I had to go _up_ a level, to the skills list, to find the other versions of my skill; I expected that to be like Lambdas where the choice of version is on the top screen of the Lambda itself rather than in the list of lambdas. Consistency of design is not Amazon's strongest skill, alas.